# Xamarin IDE Access to the Path is denied

Tags: c#, windows, xamarin, monodevelop, xamarin-studio

I'm porting over a Visual Studio C# solution with many projects and creating a new solution in the Xamarin IDE - all on windows.

I am porting / re-creating 1 project at a time and then compiling. I can compile each project individually but and then I can compile the solution (with some errors).
The problem arises if I try a Rebuild All, then it shows the error:

```
'Access to the path "[my build path\some.dll]" is denied.'
```

I have full admin rights and, as I mentioned, I originally could build the dll's so it's not an access issue.
If I try to actually delete the dll's in question, I can't - windows denies me.
If I close Xamarin, I can then delete the file manually. So, I assume, Xamarin still has a 'lock' on the file which won't allow it to be deleted.

Has anyone else seen this and if so, how did you get around it?

If this is a bug, then this makes this nearly unusable.

Comment: I have the same problem when compiling solution that consists of multiple library projects. What runtime do you use - mono or .NET?

Comment: After not finding a solution that worked with Mono, I found myself stuck and pursued it no longer. Later, I revisited this from another angle and in trying to reach my ultimate goal of running a windows program on linux, I found a solution that works pretty well. I run the program on linux under WINE (and also use winetricks).

Comment: I'm hitting this problem a couple of years later with Xamarin Studio 5.10!

Answer (score 2):

I just started with Xamarin in Windows as well and am having this problem. A quick fix I found it to switch from Debug over to Release; but this disables your debug output. Closing and reopening Xamarin has also relieved the issue for a few more debug builds.

I have found no rhyme or reason why this is occurring, seems to be at random.

Comment: ... 'relieved the issue for a few more debug builds' - I saw the same thing. This randomness is the most frustrating.

Comment: Running Xamarin Studio as Administrator worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

Check the `read-only` property of the `dll` on that path, make sure it is not checked. I had the same issue, After unchecking the read-only property, the issue resolved.

Comment: After I tried that and tried to install the packages again my entire Solution was broken.

Answer (score 0):

Remove all cache in this file C:\Users{user}.nuget\packages And update xamarin.forms